# Different reputation on Main Site and Meta

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation on the travel site is 50 but here in Travel meta, it is 43. How is that possible?

Comment: I suppose its a caching issue. Wait some minutes and it should be equal again.

Answer (score 9):

It takes a while to update on meta as well.  Give it a few minutes/hours and they'll match up.